# Making hundred of cosmetic changes to the code at the last minute

Tags: agile, methodology

A programmer keeps making cosmetic changes to the code while we have a strict deadline and the contract stipulate "no changes to the existing code". I am wondering where this "attitude" comes from: DevOps ? Agile ?

Changes performed:
1. Replacing explicit variables with "var"
2. Renaming short variable names with longer ones
3. Refactoring code injections into MVC controller classes
4. Adding design patterns (like command patttern) to existing code (with no functionality changes)
5. Adding constructors with parameters to ViewModel classes (forgetting to add a non parameter one, so the post breaks...)

Hundred and hundred of changes after tests were made, and making merging way more complicated.

Is this Agile ?

Comment: This is not what this site is for.

Comment: Most of that are not cosmetic changes.

Comment: Short answer, no. That is not agile.That can happen in any kind of team where you don't have agreed code standards that are followed and used in code reviews.

Comment: You need a team lead to set out a decent set of standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,this is not agile practices.When a programmer is doing the mentioned changes ,it means he/she is not well prepared to the project work.
Agile allows to work in collaboration where each member of the team help one another in a problem so that the final code produced will result in less change, and will be more productive than produced by an individual.

Comment: I think I found what the programmer is following: Refactoring.https://resources.collab.net/agile-101/code-refactoring